# Deleted some files by fetching data from remote repository and then commiting them, now want to restore old files

Tags: git

I am pretty new to git. Recently I am working on a project , I updated some files locally and updated files committed , i tried to push  but the remote repository  had one updated file ,

> README.md

that I did not have . So I fetched by running this line,

```
git fetch
git checkout origin/client --README.md

git add README.md
git commit -m"new Commit"
git push
```

So now I lost my updated files in locally and replaced with old files from remote repository. What can I do now to get my locally updated files back ?

Comment: please update your question to clarify: which files/local changes did you "lose"? Were they already checked in and committed? Is there anything you already tried to restore them?
These points are relevant for answering your question but are not described in it.

Comment: okay , I am editing my question now

Answer (score 0):

So, I assume you had, in your local working copy, a file named `README.md`, which was not part of the repository, when you `git clone` it the first time.

At one point, somebody added the file to the `origin` repository, and so you needed to `merge` it in your working history, to prevent `commit`/`push` errors. You `git fetch` the file from the repository, and now, effectively, you have an override of the content of your local README.md, as per [`checkout` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout):

> Updates files in the working tree to match the version in the index or the specified tree.

Then you committed the new version, which is identical to the origin version you fetch and checkout. Then, you `git push` to origin.

At this point, all edits from your local branch are in the origin repository, and the README.md file is the same it was in origin when you fetch.

> How do I get back my local copy?

Depends. If you created a local commit you wanted to push prior the fetch, try to find the SHA of that commit and git checkout the file from that commit. Then, create a new commit and push it, if you feel so.

If not, then I need to know something more about what you did prior the fetch.

Answer (score 0):

First, let me start by saying that you shouldn't get the changes to a file from a remote repository by doing:

```
git fetch
git checkout remote/branch -- path/to/file
```

unless you want to overwrite your copy of the file with the one that came from the remote repository. Conceptually, it's the equivalent of resolving a merge conflict by choosing *their* side for all differences.

The right way to [incorporate the changes from a remote repo](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches#_pulling) is by doing:

```
git pull
```

or

```
git pull --rebase
```

You can read up on the [`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) command and how it works in the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull).

---

Now, on to your specific problem.
Yes, you can recover you changes to the `README.md` file.

Assuming the latest commit in your current branch is the one with the message `"new Commit"`, here's what you can do:

1) Move `HEAD`, the index and your working directory to the previous commit (i.e. the one with *your* changes to `README.md`):

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

2) Rebase your commit on top of the latest commit from the remote repository (i.e. the one with the *their* changes to `README.md`)

```
git pull --rebase origin client
```

3) At this point, your commit will be after the one from the remote repository and it will include your changes (assuming you're resolved any conflicts in the previous step). Now, you can safely push your commit to the remote repo:

```
git push origin client
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets go, if you had committed your changes locally and after a push and the remote repository denied it, it's because the files were conflicting, one thing to do in this situation is to update your local branch and then merge your branch with the remote branch.

```
git pull //updating your branch
git merge branchname //merge your branch
```

After that if there is any conflict just resolve and raise your modifications again, because your branch will be in line with your remote branch and the remote branch will allow you to push.

If you have lost your modifications, use the command

```
git log
```

and check if your commit is there, if you find it just reset it to the state of that commit and everything from its timeline forward will be undone